# GUI imagesc malfunction

Tags: matlab, user-interface

Image of error:

[image: screen capture]

I am using MATLAB to run a behavioral analysis GUI based on LFP recorded from mice. However, when I am loading up the screen I get a large blue square covering the majority of the plot as shown in the attached figure. The data under it is intact. It is happening in this line:

```
% Plot the spectrogram:
handles.LFPfig = axes('Position',[.05 .13 .9 .75],'visible','off','Parent',handles.f);
colormap parula

axes(handles.LFPfig);
psd_axes_pos = handles.LFPfig.Position;
max_LFP_y = 148; % 148 = 15 Hz
imagesc(handles.D.pX,( handles.D.F(1:max_LFP_y) ),10*log10(abs(handles.D.P(1:max_LFP_y,:))));

set(handles.LFPfig,'ydir','normal','visible','off')
imagesc(handles.D.pX,( handles.D.F(1:max_LFP_y)),10*log10(abs(handles.D.P(1:max_LFP_y,:))));
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Are you calling `imagesc` twice or is this a typo?

Comment: Please read this bit of the documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html#bux1nfb-1 You'll see that you are calling the high-level version of `imagesc`, which means it is likely creating new axes. Try using the form `imagesc('XData',...,'YData',...,'CData',...)` instead.